# How do I need to show the Selected Account in the Dropdownlist box using Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have this code in my View..

```
<tr><td>Account:</td><td><%=Html.DropDownList("drdAccounts",Model.AccountsListHeader),Model.selectedAccount,"Select Account", new { onchange = "JavaScript:AccountChanged()" })%><span class="requiredAsterisk">*</span></td></tr>
```

But I am getting Error

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected
```

is that I am doing something wrong in this line?
How to show the Selected account on the Dropdown list box?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a closing parenthesis that you need to remove:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("drdAccounts", Model.AccountsListHeader, 
    Model.selectedAccount, "Select Account", 
    new { onchange = "JavaScript:AccountChanged()" }
) %>
```

This being said I would recommend you using the strongly typed [DropDownListFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834953.aspx) helper method to generate dropdown lists:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.selectedAccount, Model.AccountsListHeader, 
    "Select Account", new { id = "accounts" }) %>
```

And then use jquery to attach a [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler unobtrusively:

```
$(function() {
    $('#accounts').change(function() {
        // TODO: do something when the current value changes
    });
});
```

Comment: I used strongly typed DropdownListFor but I am not able to show the Selected Account name in the Dropdown list box? Thanks

Comment: Simply set the `SelectedAccount` property on your view model to the desired value (value, not text) inside the controller action rendering this view.